# In large sample, does IV fit better than OLS?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables

This is taken from Hansen's econometrics textbook.

Take the linear model:

$$Y = Z\beta + e $$

Let the residuals in an IV regression be  $\tilde  e$  and in an OLS regression $\hat e$. If X is indeed endogeneous, will IV fit better than OLS in the sense that $\tilde e' \tilde e$ < $\hat e' \hat e$?

Comment: I am guessing from context that "IV" refers to [instrument variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation) rather than [independent variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables).

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't being clear